# Is there any way to run the python script with django project?

Tags: mysql, json, django, python-3.x

I am new to django and python. I have created a django web application, I also have a python script which I have to run at the backend of the web application in real-time(Like it should always check for new updates and tell the web about new responses from the API by generating notifications). I am using an IBM-Qradar API from which I have to display the data on the web application.

I have two problems
1) Is there any way I can use the below python code with my django project just like I described above?
2) and use the  API response which is in json format to store the data into MySQL database directly from response variable.

I could Only find ways to store data into the database by using forms, which is not required for my project.

```
import json
import os
import sys

import importlib
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('../modules'))
client_module = importlib.import_module('RestApiClient')
SampleUtilities = importlib.import_module('SampleUtilities')


def main():

    # First we have to create our client
    client = client_module.RestApiClient(version='9.0')

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Basic 'GET'
    # In this example we'll be using the GET endpoint of siem/offenses without
    # any parameters. This will print absolutely everything it can find, every
    # parameter of every offense.

    # Send in the request
    SampleUtilities.pretty_print_request(client, 'siem/offenses', 'GET')
    response = client.call_api('siem/offenses', 'GET')

    # Check if the success code was returned to ensure the call to the API was
    # successful.
    if (response.code != 200):
        print('Failed to retrieve the list of offenses')
        SampleUtilities.pretty_print_response(response)
        sys.exit(1)

    # Since the previous call had no parameters and response has a lot of text,
    # we'll just print out the number of offenses
    response_body = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
    print('Number of offenses retrieved: ' + str(len(response_body)))

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Using the fields parameter with 'GET'
    # If you just print out the result of a call to the siem/offenses GET
    # endpoint there will be a lot of fields displayed which you have no
    # interest in. Here, the fields parameter will make sure the only the
    # fields you want are displayed for each offense.

    # Setting a variable for all the fields that are to be displayed
    fields = '''id%2Cstatus%2Cdescription%2Coffense_type%2Coffense_source%2Cmagnitude%2Csource_network%2Cdestination_networks%2Cassigned_to'''

    # Send in the request
    SampleUtilities.pretty_print_request(client, 'siem/offenses?fields='+fields, 'GET')
    response = client.call_api('siem/offenses?fields=' +fields, 'GET')


    # Once again, check the response code
    if (response.code != 200):
        print('Failed to retrieve list of offenses')
        SampleUtilities.pretty_print_response(response)
        sys.exit(1)

    # This time we will print out the data itself
    #SampleUtilities.pretty_print_response(response)

    response_body = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
    print(response_body)
    print(type(response_body))
    for i in response_body:
        print(i)
        print("")

    for j in response_body:
        print(j['id'])
        print(j['status'])
        print(j['description'])
```

Comment: Basically you are looking for a cronjob. You can use [**`celery`**](http://www.celeryproject.org/). Here is a [**`documentation`**](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) on how to integrate django with celery.

Comment: @ruddra you don't need celery to run cron jobs...

Comment: you are right. alternative to cron job is to use celery periodic tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own management commands, and invoke them with

```
myprojectpath/manage.py mycommand args ...
```

The documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Note that this is required, if you wish to utilize Django models. There is a lot of environment setup which this will do for you behind the scenes. If you try to just import and use django models into a vanilla Python script, they won't work right.